# No Connection with Pivpn wireguard lxc Container on a proxmox host

Tags: port-forwarding, proxmox, lxc, wireguard

#### Describe the issue

I can't connect to anything. Not the internet nor the local network

#### Expected behavior

I want if my device is connected to the wireguard vpn to surf the web and to access every device which is connected to the wireguard vpn.

#### Please describe the steps to replicate the issue

Running `bash -c "$(wget -qLO - https://github.com/tteck/Proxmox/raw/main/ct/wireguard.sh)"` on the Proxmox Host.
initializing it with vmid 105 and  the static internal vmbr1 ip to 10.0.0.105/32.
Port Forwarding with `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i vmbr0 -p udp --dport 51280 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.105:51820` on the Proxmox Host
Adding

```
lxc.cgroup2.devices.allow: c 10:200 rwm
lxc.mount.entry: /dev/net dev/net none bind,create=dir
```

to /etc/pve/lxc/105.conf at the EOF
`chown 100000:100000 /dev/net/tun` on the Proxmox Host
Shutdown the LXC and Start
Adding a client with `pivpn add` and then generating qr with `pivpn -qr` trying to connect and seems to work but cant reach anything.

Additional Information:
It's a root server. Every port is open.
vmbr0 has the eno1 slave and is the connection to the internet with the public ip
vmbr1 is the internal lan.

#### Have you taken any steps towards solving your issue?

Tried `pivpn -d`, no errors

```
::: Generating Debug Output
::::            PiVPN debug              ::::
=============================================
::::            Latest commit            ::::
Branch: master
Commit: 4032a55c80f25b51419180eda93f44d579ab79e9
Author: 4s3ti
Date: Wed Mar 29 14:54:19 2023 +0200
Summary: docs(issues): Remove old markdown template
=============================================
::::        Installation settings        ::::
PLAT=Debian
OSCN=bullseye
USING_UFW=0
pivpnforceipv6route=1
IPv4dev=eth0
install_user=root
install_home=/root
VPN=wireguard
pivpnPORT=51820
pivpnDNS1=1.1.1.1
pivpnDNS2=8.8.8.8
pivpnHOST=REDACTED
INPUT_CHAIN_EDITED=0
FORWARD_CHAIN_EDITED=0
INPUT_CHAIN_EDITEDv6=
FORWARD_CHAIN_EDITEDv6=
pivpnPROTO=udp
pivpnMTU=1420
pivpnPERSISTENTKEEPALIVE=25
pivpnDEV=wg0
pivpnNET=10.6.0.0
subnetClass=24
pivpnenableipv6=0
ALLOWED_IPS="0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0"
UNATTUPG=1
INSTALLED_PACKAGES=(git dnsutils grepcidr net-tools bsdmainutils iptables-persistent wireguard-tools qrencode linux-headers-amd64 wireguard-dkms unattended-upgrades)
=============================================
::::  Server configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = server_priv
Address = 10.6.0.1/24
MTU = 1420
ListenPort = 51820
### begin t ###
[Peer]
PublicKey = t_pub
PresharedKey = t_psk
AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.2/32
### end t ###
=============================================
::::  Client configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = t_priv
Address = 10.6.0.2/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8

[Peer]
PublicKey = server_pub
PresharedKey = t_psk
Endpoint = REDACTED:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25
=============================================
::::    Recursive list of files in       ::::
::::    /etc/wireguard shown below       ::::
/etc/wireguard:
configs
keys
wg0.conf

/etc/wireguard/configs:
clients.txt
t.conf

/etc/wireguard/keys:
server_priv
server_pub
t_priv
t_psk
t_pub
=============================================
::::            Self check               ::::
:: [OK] IP forwarding is enabled
:: [OK] Iptables MASQUERADE rule set
:: [OK] WireGuard is running
:: [OK] WireGuard is enabled 
(it will automatically start on reboot)
:: [OK] WireGuard is listening on port 51820/udp
=============================================
:::: Having trouble connecting? Take a look at the FAQ:
:::: https://docs.pivpn.io/faq
=============================================
:::: WARNING: This script should have automatically masked sensitive       ::::
:::: information, however, still make sure that PrivateKey, PublicKey      ::::
:::: and PresharedKey are masked before reporting an issue. An example key ::::
:::: that you should NOT see in this log looks like this:                  ::::
:::: YIAoJVsdIeyvXfGGDDadHh6AxsMRymZTnnzZoAb9cxRe                          ::::
=============================================
::::            Debug complete           ::::
::: 
::: Debug output completed above.
::: Copy saved to /tmp/debug.log
:::
```

did: WireGuard, restart the server with sudo systemctl restart wg-quick@wg0. Run lsmod | grep wireguard and confirm that you get at least this output (numbers don't matter).
result:

```
root@wireguard:~# systemctl restart wg-quick@wg0
root@wireguard:~# lsmod | grep wireguard
wireguard              94208  0
curve25519_x86_64      36864  1 wireguard
libchacha20poly1305    16384  1 wireguard
libcurve25519_generic    49152  2 curve25519_x86_64,wireguard
ip6_udp_tunnel         16384  1 wireguard
udp_tunnel             24576  1 wireguard
```

did: Check that the current IP address of the interface IPv4dev is the same as IPv4addr. You can see the current IP with ip -f inet address show IPv4dev.
result:

```
root@wireguard:~# ip -f inet address show eth0
2: eth0@if63: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000 link-netnsid 0
    inet 10.0.0.105/32 brd 10.0.0.105 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I also tried here to setup the lxc with 10.0.0.105/24 cidr, didn't worked.

did: Check that the current public IP of your connection is the same as pivpnHOST. To check the current public IP: curl -s https://checkip.amazonaws.com.
result: true

did: Packet capture at proxmox host
result:

```
root@PXHOST ~ # tcpdump -n -i eno1 udp port 51820
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v[v]... for full protocol decode
listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
20:24:37.247653 IP PUBLIC_IP_FROM_DEVICE.23135 > PUBLIC_IP_FROM_PROXMOXHOST.51820: UDP, length 148
20:24:42.407118 IP PUBLIC_IP_FROM_DEVICE.24914 > PUBLIC_IP_FROM_PROXMOXHOST.51820: UDP, length 148
20:24:47.408793 IP PUBLIC_IP_FROM_DEVICE.3965 > PUBLIC_IP_FROM_PROXMOXHOST.51820: UDP, length 148
20:24:52.417794 IP PUBLIC_IP_FROM_DEVICE.15818 > PUBLIC_IP_FROM_PROXMOXHOST.51820: UDP, length 148
20:24:57.427425 IP PUBLIC_IP_FROM_DEVICE.25774 > PUBLIC_IP_FROM_PROXMOXHOST.51820: UDP, length 148
20:25:02.427643 IP PUBLIC_IP_FROM_DEVICE.10110 > PUBLIC_IP_FROM_PROXMOXHOST.51820: UDP, length 148
20:25:07.436955 IP PUBLIC_IP_FROM_DEVICE.14914 > PUBLIC_IP_FROM_PROXMOXHOST.51820: UDP, length 148
20:25:12.448197 IP PUBLIC_IP_FROM_DEVICE.29891 > PUBLIC_IP_FROM_PROXMOXHOST.51820: UDP, length 148
20:25:17.440071 IP PUBLIC_IP_FROM_DEVICE.7570 > PUBLIC_IP_FROM_PROXMOXHOST.51820: UDP, length 148
20:25:22.460508 IP PUBLIC_IP_FROM_DEVICE.21590 > PUBLIC_IP_FROM_PROXMOXHOST.51820: UDP, length 148
```

tried to edit /etc/wireguard/wg0.conf and add postup and postdown rules, restart machine reconnect device
PostUp : `iptables -A FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -A FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
PostDown: `iptables -D FORWARD -i %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -D FORWARD -o %i -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`
result: no connection to the internet nor the local network

#### Screenshots

*No response*

#### Where did you run pivpn?

Proxmox LXC Container

#### Please provide your output from `uname -a`

Host:

```
Linux PXHOST 5.19.17-2-pve #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC PVE 5.19.17-2 (Sat, 28 Jan 2023 16:40:25  x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

LXC:

```
Linux wireguard 5.19.17-2-pve #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC PVE 5.19.17-2 (Sat, 28 Jan 2023 16:40:25  x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

#### Details about Operative System

HOST:

```
cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

LXC:

```
root@wireguard:~# cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

#### Installation

````
✓ Started LXC Container
+ '[' debian == alpine ']'
++ wget -qLO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tteck/Proxmox/main/install/wireguard-install.sh
+ lxc-attach -n 105 -- bash -c '#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Copyright (c) 2021-2023 tteck
# Author: tteck (tteckster)
# License: MIT
# https://github.com/tteck/Proxmox/raw/main/LICENSE


Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
+ apt-get autoclean
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
+ msg_ok Cleaned
+ local msg=Cleaned
+ echo -e '\r\033[K \033[1;92m✓\033[m \033[1;92mCleaned\033[m'
 ✓ Cleaned
+ description
++ pct exec 105 ip a s dev eth0
++ awk '/inet / {print $2}'
++ cut -d/ -f1
+ IP=10.0.0.105
+ pct set 105 -description '# Wireguard LXC
  ### https://tteck.github.io/Proxmox/
  <a href='\''https://ko-fi.com/D1D7EP4GF'\''><img src='\''https://img.shields.io/badge/☕-Buy me a coffee-red'\'' /></a>'
+ msg_ok 'Completed Successfully!\n'
+ local 'msg=Completed Successfully!\n'
+ echo -e '\r\033[K \033[1;92m✓\033[m \033[1;92mCompleted Successfully!\n\033[m'
 ✓ Completed Successfully!```

### Profile / Client creation

pivpn add
Enter a Name for the Client: t
::: Client Keys generated
::: Client config generated
::: Updated server config
::: WireGuard reloaded
======================================================================
::: Done! t.conf successfully created!
::: t.conf was copied to /root/configs for easytransfer.
::: Please use this profile only on one device and create additional
::: profiles for other devices. You can also use pivpn -qr
::: to generate a QR Code you can scan with the mobile app.
======================================================================

### Debug output


::: Generating Debug Output
::::            PiVPN debug              ::::
=============================================
::::            Latest commit            ::::
````

## Branch: master
Commit: 4032a55c80f25b51419180eda93f44d579ab79e9
Author: 4s3ti
Date: Wed Mar 29 14:54:19 2023 +0200
Summary: docs(issues): Remove old markdown template

## ::::        Installation settings        ::::
PLAT=Debian
OSCN=bullseye
USING_UFW=0
pivpnforceipv6route=1
IPv4dev=eth0
install_user=root
install_home=/root
VPN=wireguard
pivpnPORT=51820
pivpnDNS1=1.1.1.1
pivpnDNS2=8.8.8.8
pivpnHOST=REDACTED
INPUT_CHAIN_EDITED=0
FORWARD_CHAIN_EDITED=0
INPUT_CHAIN_EDITEDv6=
FORWARD_CHAIN_EDITEDv6=
pivpnPROTO=udp
pivpnMTU=1420
pivpnPERSISTENTKEEPALIVE=25
pivpnDEV=wg0
pivpnNET=10.6.0.0
subnetClass=24
pivpnenableipv6=0
ALLOWED_IPS="0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0"
UNATTUPG=1
INSTALLED_PACKAGES=(git dnsutils grepcidr net-tools bsdmainutils iptables-persistent wireguard-tools qrencode linux-headers-amd64 wireguard-dkms unattended-upgrades)

::::  Server configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = server_priv
Address = 10.6.0.1/24
MTU = 1420
ListenPort = 51820

#### begin t

[Peer]
PublicKey = t_pub
PresharedKey = t_psk
AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.2/32

#### end t

=============================================
::::  Client configuration shown below   ::::
[Interface]
PrivateKey = t_priv
Address = 10.6.0.2/24
DNS = 1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8

## [Peer]
PublicKey = server_pub
PresharedKey = t_psk
Endpoint = REDACTED:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0, ::0/0
PersistentKeepalive = 25

::::    Recursive list of files in       ::::
::::    /etc/wireguard shown below       ::::
/etc/wireguard:
configs
keys
wg0.conf

/etc/wireguard/configs:
clients.txt
t.conf

## /etc/wireguard/keys:
server_priv
server_pub
t_priv
t_psk
t_pub

## ::::            Self check               ::::
:: [OK] IP forwarding is enabled
:: [OK] Iptables MASQUERADE rule set
:: [OK] WireGuard is running
:: [OK] WireGuard is enabled
(it will automatically start on reboot)
:: [OK] WireGuard is listening on port 51820/udp

## :::: Having trouble connecting? Take a look at the FAQ:
:::: https://docs.pivpn.io/faq

## :::: WARNING: This script should have automatically masked sensitive       ::::
:::: information, however, still make sure that PrivateKey, PublicKey      ::::
:::: and PresharedKey are masked before reporting an issue. An example key ::::
:::: that you should NOT see in this log looks like this:                  ::::
:::: YIAoJVsdIeyvXfGGDDadHh6AxsMRymZTnnzZoAb9cxRe                          ::::

::::            Debug complete           ::::
:::
::: Debug output completed above.
::: Copy saved to /tmp/debug.log
:::